# Does a Ghost EMP work on Command Centers and other buildings?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

If so we could block the MULEs and scans, etc.

What about other buildings?

I'm assuming it will wipe Protoss shields. That means if you have a double ghost you could throw down a nuke with one and EMP with the other right before the nuke hits.

Comment: PS: an edit was made to add strategy tag but I think this is more of a tactic than a strategy, coined a tactics tag

Comment: One ghost with some energy built up can actually emp and nuke by itself. For an awesome example as well as just some general ownage, see http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3980787/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, EMP will drain the energy of buildings. It will also do, IIRC, 100 damage to shields, but not necessarily take them out completely.

I have not confirmed, but I have read that it will also reveal cloaked and burrowed units for a period of item as well.

Comment: it does reveal cloaked units

Comment: @Eric do you know how long it de-cloaks units for? If you fire one at a mothership and de-cloak all the units next to it, how long do you get before they re-cloak?

Comment: @Nick 7 seconds real time (10 seconds Starcraft time). Note: The new Protoss expansion will use real time instead of blizzard time.